# Spring Integration / Shared ConnectionFactory Between RedisDrivenEndpoint

Tags: redis, spring-integration, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I'm actually trying to implements with Spring Integration multiple RedisEndpoint to receive information from Queues from a Redis Database.

I've done multiple configurations with one RedisPoint each.
For example:

Endpoint One:

```java
    @Bean
    RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint redisQueueMessageDrivenEndpointStopMonitoring() {
        RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint endpoint =
                new RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint(REDIS_QUEUE_NOTIFICATION_SM, SpringIntegrationConfig.getLettuceConnectionFactory(CLIENT_NAME_SM_NOTIFICATION));
        endpoint.setOutputChannelName(SUBSCRIPTION_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_SM);
        endpoint.setAutoStartup(true);
        endpoint.setSerializer(serializer());
        endpoint.setTaskExecutor(SpringIntegrationConfig.taskExecutor());
        return endpoint;
    }
```

Endpoint Two:

```java
    @Bean
    RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint redisQueueMessageDrivenEndpointStopMonitoringError() {
        RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint endpoint =
                new RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint(REDIS_QUEUE_NOTIFICATION_UNAVAILABLE_SM, SpringIntegrationConfig.getLettuceConnectionFactory(CLIENT_NAME_SM_SUBSCRIPTION_ERROR));
        endpoint.setOutputChannelName(NOTIFY_SM_PRODUCER_UNAVAILABLE_CHANNEL);
        endpoint.setAutoStartup(true);
        endpoint.setSerializer(serializer());
        endpoint.setTaskExecutor(SpringIntegrationConfig.taskExecutor());
        return endpoint;
    }
```

And here's the configuration for the ConnectionFactory:

```java
@Import(value = { StopMonitoringIntegrationConfig.class, StopMonitoringErrorIntegrationConfig.class })
public class SpringIntegrationConfig {

    // Redis Params
    @Value("${redis.param.zip}")
    public static Boolean REDIS_ZIP_BOOLEAN_PARAMS = false;

    // Executor Params
    @Value("${task.executor.pool-size}")
    public static Integer SUBSCRIPTION_INITIALISATION_EXECUTOR = 15;
    @Value("${task.executor.queue-capacity}")
    public static Integer TASK_EXECUTOR_QUEUE_CAPACITY = 1000;

    public static final String FALSE = "false";
    public static final String TRUE = "true";

    // TODO : "{task.executor.fixed-delay}"
    public static final String TASK_EXECUTOR_FIXED_DELAY_PROPERTY = "1";
    public static final String TASK_EXECUTOR = "taskExecutor";


    // Executor: Execute la tache demandee par le ServiceActivator

    @Bean(TASK_EXECUTOR)
    public static ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.setCorePoolSize(SpringIntegrationConfig.SUBSCRIPTION_INITIALISATION_EXECUTOR);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(SpringIntegrationConfig.TASK_EXECUTOR_QUEUE_CAPACITY);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    public static LettuceConnectionFactory getLettuceConnectionFactory(String clientName) {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName("HOSTNAME");
        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                .clientOptions(
                        ClientOptions.builder()
                                .socketOptions(
                                        SocketOptions.builder()
                                                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(10000))
                                                .build())
                                .build())
                .commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10000))
                .clientName(clientName)
                .build();

        LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, clientConfiguration);
        connectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return connectionFactory;
    }
```

I don't put it the the rest of the flow (it works well :D )

What i'm not getting there is that when i check the number of client on redis-cli, my two ClientConnection are in double
[Redis-cli client list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHReL.png)

Can someone explain me why?

And by the way i wanted to have a single implementation of a LettuceConnectionFactory (idem for the TaskExecutor Bean) so i've decided to put it in the Main Configuration and acces it in a static way but I don't know if it is the right way to do this with the Spring Context and @Bean, i've read a something about it but didn't find something really clear.

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT**

Reply to Artem first comment :

So if i understand it right :
In the main configuration :

```java
    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceBeanFactory() { // instanciation logic here }
```

In the subConfig :

Constructor Injection :

```java
    @Autowired
    public StopMonitoringIntegrationConfig(SiriNotifierFilterService siriNotificationContentFilter, TaskExecutor taskExecutor, LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceBeanFactory) {
        // Assignation bean to a parameter}
```

And within the @Bean RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint :

```java
    @Bean
    RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint redisQueueMessageDrivenEndpointStopMonitoring() {
        RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint endpoint =
                new RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint(REDIS_QUEUE_NOTIFICATION_SM, lettuceBeanFactory); }
```

Yes maybe forgot to mention that I want to have separated sub config for each RedisEndpoint (with inside specific logic IntegrationFlow, Routing, etc...)

Comment: Why don't make those `LettuceConnectionFactory` as beans? Right now you call a factory method from every single place. Consider to expose those client-specific factories as beans and inject already those beans in the target channel adapter definitions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I tried to understand what you said and i've done an EDIT on my post

Comment: Right, you can have several `LettuceConnectionFactory` beans according to your requirement. Then you use a `@Qualifier` in the place where you are going to inject a desired `CF`.

Comment: Ok, i noticed that with the @Bean definition of the LettuceConnectionFactory i'm not able to set the client connection after injection of the bean( or use setClientName but it is deprecated)

Back to my first question, for each endpoint I noticed that i have 2 client connection by endpoint definition, is this normal or is there something wrong?

Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about that.